# Storing data from SQL in array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am trying to store the data from my sql database into an array.  Currently I have this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `InspEmail` WHERE  `Company` LIKE  '$company'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {

        $inspector = $row['name'];

    }
```

The problem is that I have 8 rows of data.  I need to store each 8 names from that database into an array.  When I try this:

```
$inspector = array($row['name']);
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for all the great answers!!  Works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is:

```
$inspector[] = $row['name'];
```

This will store all 8 names in an array similar to:

```
array(
     [0] => name1
     [1] => name2
     [2] => name3

)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to store all of the names in an array, you need to define the array outside the scope of the while loop and append to it. Like this:

```
$nameArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    // Append to the array
    $nameArray[] = $row['name'];   
}
```

Comment: technically you don't have to define it outside the loop. However, I am always a fan of declaring variables so you can document them.

Comment: You're right! I often forget php lets you append to an uninitialized array.

Comment: It actually throws a notice. though most have notices turned off.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of good answers. But if you do this often, you might want to write a little function:

```
mysql_field_array($sql, $fieldname)
{
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $a = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        $a[] = $row[$fieldname];
    }
    mysql_free_result($res);
    return $a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line...

```
$inspector = $row['name'];
```

...with this:

```
$inspector [] = $row['name'];
```

After that, the inspector array contains all the names.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `InspEmail` WHERE  `Company` LIKE  '$company'");
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $inspector[] = $row;
}
for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($row);$i++)
{
  $data = $inspector[$i];
}
return $data;
```

Check it...